# Voltage Calculate

Tags: voltage, resistance, current-source

[image]

I want to calculate Vo by Thevenin's theorem. First I removed the RL(1k)

[image]

Now I have to calculate Vth. Can I say that Vth is 6V? or Vth=6V + voltage through 2k?

If both these options are wrong, then tell me any law or procedure to find Vth?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: you can say that Vo is 6v more than the voltage on the end of the 2k. What's the voltage across the 1k resistor? What's the voltage across the 2k resistor?

Comment: @Neil_UK you forgot Ix * 2K

Comment: The answer to your two questions are ... 1.) No, and 2.) yes.

Comment: That's the crux of the problem, with no load Ix = 0 and therefore the current generator produces no current and hence the output is 6 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka yes the answer can only be algebraic. NAN

Comment: @Trevor_G If V0 is not 6V , then how can I calculate it? Any law or theorem which I can apply?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework with no real attempt shown to solve it

Comment: @TonyM I am not asking you to do my homework, I was just solving this circuit by thevenin's theorem and I got stuck in this point so I asked my point directly instead of telling my whole previous calculations.

Comment: @Trevor_G Not sure why are you saying this... no current implies it is 6V indeed... the Thevenin equivalent of the current source will be a zero volt voltage... Unless this circuit is incomplete.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are right I may be thinking this backwards. Where 2Ix is the controlled part and Ix is the resultant current division. Rethinking with Ix as the measured value and 2Ix as the secondary value probably makes more sense. In which case with no load Vo is indeed 6V.

Comment: As you can see from the on-hold, that's not the way the site works, I'm afraid Tom. Please do reword the question, as I suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

With an unloaded output (as per the picture above) Ix must be zero and this means that the current generator output is zero and it therefore follows that the terminal output voltage (into an infinite impedance load) is 6 volts.

If the output were loaded then this requires a tad more thinking.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, is Vo will be 6V or -6 V?

Comment: Vout polarity will correspond to the + and - symbols on the diagram.

Comment: Replace the stuff on the left with it's Thevenin equivalent and tell yourself.

Comment: Well,I guess it will be 6V then, right ? @Andyaka

Comment: @Tom that's what I thought I was saying!

Comment: Good, I was just confused that may be Vo=6+voltage across 2k but Now I know that Vo=6

Comment: @Tom if you are happy with this answer then please consider formally accepting it and it's a shame your question was put on hold.

Comment: who in the world put this on hold? The answer the question is 6V because its an open circuit, which will always be the source voltage in a non conducting (in this case, opened) circuit. Btw, this is one of the basic things you learn when you are learning electronics repair.